# Multiple services with web based user interface in the same server

Tags: service, server, dns

I have a server with multiple services and tools with web based user interface (rundeck, jenkins, sonarqube,...) and I want the devteam can access with a properly url, not the server IP and a port.
IE:
- companyName-rundeck.com
- companyName-jenkins.com
- companyName-sonarqube.com

What would be the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is most often use for this purpose is some kind of [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). I will describe the simple Apache setup, but it should be as easy to configure it using nginx or HAProxy.

For example purposes, let's sat that you have 3 services running on the server:

- Jenkins on port 8080
- SonarQube on port 9000
- RunDeck on port 4440

First, in order to distinguish between services just by using domain name, you will need to create several entries in your DNS, pointing the names to the server IP address:

```
jenkins.example.com  A  192.0.2.2
sonar.example.com    A  192.0.2.2
rundeck.example.com  A  192.0.2.2
```

Next, (if you have not already done that) install Apache HTTP server:

```
yum install httpd
```

Create a file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName jenkins.example.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass           /     http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse    /     http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sonar.example.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass           /     http://localhost:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse    /     http://localhost:9000/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName rundeck.example.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass           /     http://localhost:4440/
  ProxyPassReverse    /     http://localhost:4440/
</VirtualHost>
```

(the logic should be quite clear, for detailed explanation, look at [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html))

After that, just start the httpd service: `service httpd start`.

- The instructions are for CentOS, but should not differ too much for other distros
- In case it does not work as expected (without any obvious trace in logs) try with disabled selinux (`setenforce 0` && `service httpd restart`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will try it